# Remove string with unknown contents in side with javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, iframe

I'm confident that I have to use regular expressions. I have the following string:
`<iframe width="100" height="100" src="hello.html`
and i want it to say the following:
hello.html
is there a way to remove the `<iframe -> src="`
(since the width and height will be unknown?

Comment: If your string only consists of that, use `string = string.substr(string.indexOf('src="')+5)`

Comment: @RobW add that as an answer, that's better than regex. (Also it should be `+10` to accomodate the extension)

Comment: @Mathletics It's `+5`, because `src="` equals 5 characters.

Comment: I suspect the src will be arbitrary, even though the question isn't clear. It may need to be more like `string = string.substr(string.indexOf('src="')+5); string = string.substr(0, string.indexOf('"'));`

Comment: @RobW whoops! Haven't had my coffee yet.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
'<iframe width="100" height="100" src="hello.html'.replace(/<iframe width=\"\d+\" height=\"\d+\" src=\"/, '');
```